# Question about outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

I have a question about an exercise, any help will be thankful.

Let $X$ be a set and $\mu: 2^{X} \to  [ 0,+ \infty]$

Which satisfies:

-$\mu ( \emptyset) =0$

-$\mu (A)=1$ if $A$ is a pointwise subset of $X$

-$\mu (A) = \sqrt{3} $ if  $A$ has at least  two different  elements

Show that  that $\phi$ is an outer measure.\

I've  reach the firts two conditions of **outer measuer** with the 3 initial conditions of the hypothesis, the last one is the  **countable subadditivity** property

I was thinking something like this:

Take $(A_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ as $(\lbrace a_1 \rbrace ,\lbrace \lbrace a_1 \rbrace, \lbrace a_2 \rbrace \rbrace ,...)$ such that

$\mu ( \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} A_n)=\sqrt 3 \leq \mu(A_1) + \mu(A_2) +...+ =1+ \sqrt 3 +\sqrt 3+...=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \mu (A_n)$

and therefore

$\mu ( \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} A_n)\leq \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \mu (A_n)$

I do not know if it is the easiest way to do it but I can not find a way to prove the last point of the definition, any help will be very grateful.

By the way, English is not my mother lenguage, forgiveness for grammatical errors

Comment: What do  you mean by "if $A$ is a pointwise subset of $X$"? Do you mean that $A$ is a singleton (a set containing exactly one element)?

Comment: Yes,It was a mistake on my translation, what I wanted to refer  was a singleton. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot assume what $(A_{n})$ is, rather, we know that if $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n}A_{n}$ contains two or more elements, then $\mu\left(\displaystyle\bigcup_{n}A_{n}\right)=\sqrt{3}$, in this case, we can consider if there are two sets $A_{N}$ and $A_{M}$ that contains only one element each, then $\mu(A_{N})+\mu(A_{M})=2>\sqrt{3}$, so it is definitely true that $\displaystyle\sum_{n}\mu(A_{n})\geq\mu(A_{N})+\mu(A_{M})\geq\mu\left(\displaystyle\bigcup_{n}A_{n}\right)$, or we can consider there is some $A_{K}$ that contains two or more elements, then $\displaystyle\sum_{n}\mu(A_{n})\geq\mu(A_{K})=\sqrt{3}=\mu\left(\displaystyle\bigcup_{n}A_{n}\right)$.

Since $\mu\left(\displaystyle\bigcup_{n}A_{n}\right)$ cannot be strictly greater than $\sqrt{3}$, by considering the case that $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n}A_{n}$ has two or more elements suffices for the proof.

Comment: You were very clear, I was going to the side of building the sequence of sets with elements one by one, one by one ... etc, I went with that idea by the hypothesis, but you made the concept very clear.